# How to parse JSON response?

Tags: android, json

I have called webservice and got a response as below please tell me how can I parse it.....

```
FillAutoCompleteBudgetMasterItemsByMasterIdResponse{
FillAutoCompleteBudgetMasterItemsByMasterIdResult=anyType{
string=Agrochemicals; string=Certification fee; string=Consultation; 
string=Contracts; string=Electricity; string=Fertilizers; string=Fuel;
string=Implements and Equipments; string=Insurance; string=Irrigation and Water;
string=Labours; string=Machinery usage; string=Marketing; string=Other Items; 
string=Post Production; string=Repairs and Maintenance; string=Seeds/Seedlings ;
string=Services; string=Training; string=Transportation; }; }
```

Comment: I don't know may be this is in string format will you please tell me how fetch all the fields which are next to "string=".....ex 1.Agrochemicals 2.Certification 3.Consultation......

Comment: Actually I thought this is in Json format but it's not in JSON format so now I am searching for the way how I can parse the above result and can get all the fields following "string=" this.....please need your help

Answer (score 4):

This not a valid Response data.Beacuse it should contain a (key,value).
By using key we get the value.

```
JSONArray arObjects = new JSONArray(Respone);for(int i = 0; i < arObjects.length(); i++)
JSONObject jOb =  arObjects.getJSONObject(i);                       
String date = jOb.getString("PublishedDate");
String price = jOb.getString("introduction");
```

Answer (score 2):

This is not a valid json. The strings are not quoted.

http://json.org/example.html

Comment: also, i don't know if that is supposed to work, but the same key (string) is assigned several times

Comment: If the same key is used twice, only the last value will be retain.

Answer (score 1):

this is not valid json format..  you cant parse using Json... if the string is not in the valid json format it throws an exception ...
The String in enclosed [] braces in called josn array..
The String in enclosed {} braces in called josn object..
in general json array contain josn objects

```
JSONArray array= new JSONArray(jsonString);
for(i=0;i< array.length ;i++){
   JSONObject result = new JSONObject(array.get(i));
}
```

Comment: then what's wrong with response I got what should i do in order to retrieve that information...?

Comment: Please tell me if you know any solution? I am new in Android I have tried a lot then somehow I am able to get response from Webservice...

Comment: there is no way to parse this.. you have to use the string operations to get data..

Comment: Thanks for your reply Sir can you tell exactly how can I retrieve data from my above result string......

Comment: no need to use sir :).. can u tel me what the data u want from above string

Comment: I want to fetch all the fields which are next to "string=".....ex 1.Agrochemicals 2.Certification 3.Consultation......

Answer (score 0):

This tutorial might help you to parse the json in an easy and hassle free way. Please check [this](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/) out.